# Processor modes and interrupt masks for Cortex-M4

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-m

Can anyone help me find out what are the modes (especially their numbers) and interrupts masks for Cortex-M4.

Comment: you tried infocenter.arm.com yes?

Comment: of course, here is the link http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/index.html, but no numbers, not like for the other ARM processors (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Chdddhea.html)

Comment: there are only two modes or something like that, the cortex-m architecture does not at all resemble the typical arm architecture with respect to booting and processor modes, that is definitely described in the arm docs.  There is no doubt a cpsr or some other register with a bit that indicates the mode.  If not then simply do an experiment with hardware to find out.

Comment: If [the documentation doesn't already make it abundantly clear](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDIGFCA.html), they don't _have_ numbers because there's no need for them - you're either in an exception handler, or you aren't. The M-class exception model is wildly different from A-class.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing a migration to ARMv7. In the code version related to prior-to-ARMv7 architecture, I have a section called "ARM modes codes" and another one called "Interrupt masks". I need to find the equivalent for ARMv7. if there is no code, what should I put?